# All P2P connections fail

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, bittorrent, p2p

I have tried on two different networks and two different computers. My computer didn't work on either network and the other one did. I am unable to establish any sort of connection through torrent clients and games (Borderlands the Pre-Sequel). From what I understand, this means that there must be some issue with peer-to-peer connections. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on an MSi GE60 2OE. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What kind of error do you get ?

Comment: Check if you have a firewall active that is blocking the incoming traffic: starting from ports _6881-6889 TCP_. Check [here to see how to block p2p and do the opposite...](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/33985)

Comment: I dont get any sort of error, it just is not able to connect. It isnt a problem with the network as I have tested it on multiple, unrelated networks